# Best practice for macOS application installer (disk image) naming

Tags: desktop-application, mac-os-x, installation

Is there any naming convention or best practices to name macOS application installer (DMG file)? Should it contain words like "Install" or "Installer" or it's better to provide application name only? If application installer has several words in its name should they be separated by spaces or file name should be written in camel case?

**Example**

Let's assume that application name is "Some Mac Application". What is the best way to name DMG file?

1. Some Mac Application.dmg
2. SomeMacApplication.dmg
3. Some Mac Application Installer.dmg
4. Install Some Mac Application.dmg

**Research**

My assumption is that right approach is to call it "Some Mac Application.dmg". Here are some reasons:

1. DMG file is not an installer. It's just a volume which contain app file (bundle) which need to be dropped to Applications folder. So it's better to omit words *Install* and *Installer*;
2. Camel case is less readable than space separation.

At the same time according to competitive analyse it looks like *SomeMacApplication.dmg* is more common approach:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A lot of us can be untidy with our downloads so anything you can do to help us sort out the mess is good.

### Product Name

If I'm rooting around in my downloads folder looking for a particular piece of software then generic names like "Installer.dmg" are not helpful.

### DMG Purpose

I may be downloading a few things as DMG and they're not all going to be installers so adding 'Installer' or giving some other hint also helps.

### Version Number

If I've downloaded your product a few times how do I know which DMG in my downloads folder is the latest one? - or maybe I need an older version to overcome a compatibility issue.

### Readability

To avoid issues with URL structures you'll need to avoid using the space character. Clarity will vary depending on your product name but solutions include CamelCase, Hyphen-ation, and Under_Scores - You could, of course, use all three to denote differing levels of separation: ProductName_Installer_1-12.dmg